# Generics error "bound dismatch" using Spring SimpleJpaRepository

Tags: java, spring, generics, spring-data-jpa

i am using Spring data and when i try to create a bean of SimpleJpaRepository the compiler marks me an error. This is the code

```
@Bean
protected <domainClass, Long> SimpleJpaRepository<domainClass, **Long**> getSimpleJpaRepository(Class domainClass) {
    return new SimpleJpaRepository<>(domainClass, this.entityManager);
}
```

That Long i marked with * has the error: "Bound dismatch: the type Long is not a valid substitute for the bounded parameter  of the type SimpleJpaRepository"

However, when i write this i have no errors

```
 private SimpleJpaRepository<Client, Long> support = new SimpleJpaRepository<>(Client.class, this.entityManager);
```

So, i thought that Long probably was not implementing Serializable and that was the cause of the error, but with this last line i have no error so i assume that Long is actually implementing Serializable.

Do you know how i would have to do to make the generic method works? Thanks!

Comment: How does your `SimpleJPARepository` look like? Is it `@Transactional`?

Comment: Please ask separate question for the exception you're getting. It's not related to the title of your original question. And please don't modify the title. Ask separate question.

Comment: Sorry, my bad! i've just editted and created another post

Comment: @RohitJain Yes, it's transactional. SimpleJPARepository is an implementation of JpaRepository contained inside org.springframework.data: spring-data-jpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `Long` as generic type name, and you also supply `Long` as concrete type. Change the names to something like this

```
@Bean
protected <DC, L> SimpleJpaRepository<domainClass, Long> getSimpleJpaRepository(Class domainClass) {
    return new SimpleJpaRepository<>(domainClass, this.entityManager);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer! this compiles but i get an exception at runtime. i've just editted the post with the info